# How to use biblatex-gost with XeLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, xetex

I'm trying to make use of `biblatex-gost` package with XeLaTeX -- but it gives error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}

% bibliography:
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=gost-authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BooksOnMetals.bib}

\begin{document}

\texttt{footcite}: \footcite{__1979}

\texttt{textcite}: \textcite{__2009}

% bibliography:
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
(/home/boris/.local/lib/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-gost/biblatex-gost.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...stmedialanguage {\bbl@main@language 
                                                  }\newcommand *{\select@med...
l.324    \newcommand*{\select@medialanguage}{}}
```

The same code works fine if I replace `gost-authoryear` with `authoryear`. Bib file:

```
@book{__1979,
        title = {Физика твердого тела (комплект из 2 книг)},
        abstract = {Настоящая книга - подробный курс физики твердого тела, составленный авторами, в течение многих лет читающими курс лекций по этому предмету в Корнеллском университете (США). Книга написана с большим педагогическим мастерством, тщательно продуманы выбор и расположение материала, иллюстрации, задачи. Она представляет собой ценное пособие для читателей с различным кругом интересов и разной степенью подготовки; при этом путеводной нитью могут служить приводимые авторами рекомендации о последовательности чтения глав. 
 Книга адресована студентам, аспирантам, изучающим и ведущим физику твердого тела.},
        publisher = {Мир},
        author = {Ашкрофт, Н. and Мермин, Н.},
        translator = {Михайлов, Александр},
        year = {1979}
},

@book{__2009,
        edition = {2},
        title = {Основы теории металлов},
        isbn = {978-5-9221-1097-6},
        abstract = {Изложена современная теория нормальных и сверхпроводящих металлов без использования сложных математических методов. Помимо описания классических свойств, серьезное внимание уделено актуальным проблемам: квантовым интерференционным эффектам, локализации электронов случайным потенциалом, нелинейным явлениям, взаимному влиянию сверхпроводимости и магнетизма и др. Необходимо знакомство с квантовой механикой и статистикой. 

 Для студентов и аспирантов физических специальностей вузов, а также научно-технических работников в области физики твердого тела.},
        publisher = {ФИЗМАТЛИТ},
        author = {Абрикосов, А. А.},
        year = {2009}
}
```

I read `biblatex-gost` documentation. It says nothing about the XeLaTeX. I read the code the author provides -- it uses `babel` and `latex`. The doc actually doesn't comliles on my box. But anyway it is not using XeLaTeX.

Requirements to use `biblatex-gost` are:

- Biber 1.5
- biblatex 2.5

Current version on `biblatex-gost` is 0.8. I have it all.

**Edit**:

[It turns out](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/69) that biblatex doesn't support polyglossia. But plain `authoryear` works. Might also be working with a patched `gost-authoryear`.

Comment: Actually `biblatex-gost` documentation does mention xelatex (in the beginning of sec.4) and recommends using `xecyr` and `babel`. Please try them. You use `xecyr` which, if I understand it correctly, is supposed to work with `babel`.

Comment: I don't use `babel` because I like `unicode-math` way too much (I input unicode chars with emacs). `unicode-math` requires `polyglossia` -- which can't be used with `babel`. Thank You for `biblatex-gost` so much (note: Oleg is `biblatex-gost` author).

Comment: Ok, I fixed the error you got. It's not really the support of `polyglossia`, since language selection won't work anyway, but at least you should be able to compile you file. Please take the package from the Sourceforge repo. And let me know if you have any troubles.

Comment: UPD: I created the `dev` directory on Sourceforge. You may use it instead of repo.

Comment: @OlegDomanov: I just checked the `dev` out: seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
[...]
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages
\makeatletter
\def\bbl@main@language{russian}
\makeatother
[...}
```

Comment: There is no need to use polyglossia with Russian language under xetex. It's obsolete infrmation that babel cannot be used with xetex when you need Russian.